# Silent Uninstall Chrome Isn't Working

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I'm creating a batch to automate setting up new computers and one of the programs is AVAST. When I install avast silently, it installs chrome as well. Chrome isn't a program that I'm wanting to put on and it seems there is no workaround. So now I'm trying to make it uninstall chrome silently after AVAST but it just opens a new cmd window instead of running the exe.

```
@echo off
CD /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
for /r %%f IN (setup.ex?) DO  (
    START /WAIT "%%f --uninstall --force-uninstall --multi-install --chrome --system-level"
)
pause
```

Moving the end quotation to the end of %%f just gives an error that --uninstall isn't an existing file.

I've tried this on multiple PC's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the answer... but it's too long for a comment! Are you certain that you must instqall Chrome? How did you install AVAST? Can we see the command line? If you used some kind of answer file perhaps it can be modified or perhaps you can pass arguments to your install command. Try doing the command with /? to see if you get choices.  According to this you do have a choice. https://blog.avast.com/tag/google-chrome/

"As we get close to our launch date for our new Avast! Free Antivirus, version 5 we have an exciting new agreement with Google to announce. Starting in mid-November, we will be giving our new users an option to install Google Chrome when installing Avast. And to be clear here since I think some readers were reading too much into this entry. We are not forcing Chrome on users. It is entirely up to the user–to download/install is entirely up to the user and nothing is hidden."

Comment: Got it working anyway.
    START /WAIT "" "%%f" --uninstall --force-uninstall --multi-install --chrome --system-level

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your still looking for an answer, but I was able to make your batch work.

```
CD /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
for /r %%f IN (setup.ex?) DO  (
   "%%f" --uninstall --force-uninstall --multi-install --chrome --system-level
)
```