# Uninstall unusual Google Chrome install from cmd

Tags: windows, google-chrome, cmd

I am working on some automation with a set of VMs. I need to use a particular template but must change the version of chrome installed on that template from automation.

So I must uninstall Chrome from the command line or a script.

Situation info:

- I am trying to uninstall chrome version 75.0.3770.80
- wmic does not have chrome as an installed program
- Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features does list chrome as an installed software and I can correctly uninstall it from here but only through a GUI
- It is not listed in the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall
- It is not listed in the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall
- The executable is in  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome...
- the installed setup.exe is also in C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\75.0.3770.80\Installer

Problems:

- I can't use the setup.exe installer in this location because I can not find a way of running it silently. (It has a pop up asking if you want to delete browsing data)
- Deleting the executable will not remove chrome as an installed program and will not work for me
- I can not find where chrome is listed in the registry and am not sure how to search for it in regedit

Any ideas of how I can uninstall this chrome version?

Comment: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41746022/8826818) answer